# If len(list) is not divisible by 3, then exclude last item in a function . Python 2.7.1

Tags: python, string, function, division, string-length

if you have a string

```
string='abcdefg'
```

and you wanted to check if the length of the string is divisible by 3

```
len(string)
```

what command would you use?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the modulo (division remainder) operator `%`:

```
if len(s) % 3 == 0:
    ...
```

If you want to strip the string to a length divisible by 3, use

```py
s[:len(s) // 3 * 3]
```

or

```
s[:-(len(s) % 3)]
```

Comment: Modulo is a computer science student's best friend. You don't really use it *all* that often in the workplace (although it does have its usefulness) but professors seem to absolutely adore it! I suppose it does fulfill the purpose of getting people to think more iteratively.